# How to upload more than 1 image in database in asp.net core mvc using ado.net

Tags: insert, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net

I create a form where i insert data into database in asp.net core mvc using ado.net. I am trying to insert images using that form. I created model for that. How can i insert more than one image for a single property? For example a book has many pictures, so how i can manage the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your backend,configure the Model as below:

```
 public class SomeViewModel
    {
        .......//other properties
        public IFormFileCollection Pics { get; set; }
    }
```

In your view,you could add the multiple attribute for multiple pictures:

```
@model SomeViewModel

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input asp-for="@Model.id" />
    <br />
    <input asp-for="@Model.Pics" type="file" multiple />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

The result:

[image]

For more details of file upload,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?wt.mc_id=docsexp5_personal-blog-marouill&view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: actually i make a form of house rent i insert data from that form like title, address,rent price, and some other features so now i want to add pictures from the same form and in which i like to add 10 pictures for single house.

Comment: You could show your codes and let us know what you've done and where you have trouble

Comment: i write this code now i find webhostenvironment.webrootpath null error i want that solsoutionif (ar.imge1 != null)
            {
                string folder = "image/";
                folder += ar.imge1.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                



                ar.pic1 = folder;

                string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                ar.imge1.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
                
            }

Comment: There's a similar issue on github and you could check if webhostenvironment is null first，https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6890